# Django template/view issues with carousel

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, carousel

OK, so here's the deal:

This is currently what I'm working on:

[image]

See the two arrows at the top? That's where a carousel of pictures should be. However, there are no pictures in this carousel. That is, until I click the 'Upload' Button.

[image: I used old screenshots to test the uploads.]

So, my goal is to make the pictures appear on the first page before I even click the 'upload' button.

How can I fix this problem?

My code:

#### Index.html

```
{% extends 'webportal/defaults.html' %}
{% block body %}
    {% include 'webportal/carousel.html' %}

    <br/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> So far we have been able to establish what the user tables will be have created or are in process of
                    creating
                    the ability to create, update, destroy users.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> For now this ability is limited to the main user table, however the models will be easily extended
                    to other
                    tables as they are needed</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p> Also not a lot of thought has gone into styling yet, we know that the page is suppose to resemble
                    the parent
                    organizations page. Right now we have been more focused on getting each individual component
                    working. Later we
                    will merge them into a whole. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    {% include 'webportal/info_row.html' with one=one two=two three=three %}
{% endblock %}
```

Carousel.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load filename %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for document in documents %}
                        <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
                           <div class="row">
                             <div class="col">
                               <li><a href = "{{document.docfile.url}}">{{document.docfile.name}}</a></li>
                               <img src = "{{STATIC_URL}}img/{{document|filename}}" >
                               <p align="center"><form style="text-align:center" action="{% url 'webportal:delete' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                   {% csrf_token %}
                                   <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
                                   <p>{{ form.Document.label_tag }} {{ form.Document.help_text }}</p>
                                   <p>
                                       {{ form.Document.errors }}
                                       {{ form.Document.docfile }}
                                   </p>
                                   <p><input type="submit" value="Delete" /></p>
                               </form></p>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                         </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <form action="{% url 'webportal:carousel' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
        <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from webportal.views.authentication import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from webportal.forms.forms import DocumentForm
from webportal.models import Document, DeleteForm
is_server = True
def delete(request, my_id):
    Deleted=get_object_or_404(Document, docfile=my_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=DeleteForm(request.POST, instance=Deleted)
        if form.is_valid():
            Deleted.delete()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
    else:
        form=DeleteForm(instance=Deleted)
    return render_to_response(
        'webportal/index.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )

# Redirect to the document list after POST
def carousel(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
   else:
       form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
# Load documents for the list page
   documents = Document.objects.all()
#documents=DocumentForm().
# Render list page with the documents and the form
   return render_to_response(
    'webportal/index.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

#### Models.py:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='webportal/static/img/')
class DeleteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Document
        fields=[]
```

#### Forms.py:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.ImageField(label='Select a file', help_text='max. 42 megabytes')
```

I wouldn't be surprised if what I'm trying to do is impossible. If there is a way to do this, does it involve Ajax?

Comment: It sounds like you want pictures to travel back from the future and appear before you upload them..?  :-)   I have probably misunderstood something..

Comment: Just as a note on your bootstrap.. `.container>.row>.col-md-12>p` can be rewritten more simply as `.container>p` (adding rows with full-width columns is generally not needed, and adds a lot of unnecessary markup).

Comment: The pictures I upload are stored on a server, so I don't see how they have to travel from the future. @thebjorn  Or, maybe I'm an idiot who completely botched the upload code.  We shall see.

Comment: @thebjorn duly noted about the bootstrap

Comment: @thebjorn You probably mean `.container p`, because `.container>.row>.col-md-12>p` and `.container>p` are not equivalent

Comment: @ArtjomB. Implemented this.  Do you have a way I could make the focus of the question happen?

Comment: @ArtjomB. `.container` sets the margins on the body, `.row` does a `-15px` margin, and `.col-md-12` does a `+15px` margin -- cancelling out the `.row` margin.  Since both `.col-XX-12` and `p` are full width, you can place the `p` directly inside `.container` (i.e. not nested inside `.col-md-12`, nested inside `.row`) and get the same layout with *much* less markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .py files are Python code. [In Python, *leading whitespace matters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation).

In *Views.py*, the `carousel` function does not contain valid Python code:

```
def carousel(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')
else:

 form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
# Load documents for the list page
documents = Document.objects.all()
#documents=DocumentForm().
# Render list page with the documents and the form
return render_to_response(
    'webportal/index.html',
    {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

Instead, it should probably be:

```
def carousel(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/alzheimers/')

    else:

        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form
        # Load documents for the list page
        documents = Document.objects.all()
        #documents=DocumentForm().
        # Render list page with the documents and the form
        return render_to_response(
            'webportal/index.html',
            {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
        )
```

But it is not clear if the `else` part belongs to the first or the second `if` construct.

Comment: It's been fixed. @Peter

Comment: Would ajax help me here?